# give fromdate with Todays Date and time should be 00.00.00 in ssrs reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

[image]I want to pass datetime parameter in such format that it should display today date with time 00.00.00 and todate like today date with time 23.00.00 in ssrs reports.

Answer (score 1):

Misunderstood before, you have to use `AddHours`, `AddMinutes` and `AddSeconds` in parameter's default expression:

`=Today().AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(0)`

---

**UPDATE**

You can hide time in following:

```
=CDate(Format(Today().AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(0), "MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

Comment: Thanks stanislovas for your reply. but i dont want to set default time, i have set time as 00.00.00 in parameter

Comment: thank you so much Stanislovas. its Works. but plz can you tell me how can i hide the time in parameter. i only want to hide the time but it should take date as date time

Comment: Hi  Stanislovas, thanks for your reply, but after  doing this this changes, the report is not generating data.

Comment: I want to pass date as well as time but to Stored procedure. but need to hide time only in parameter, after updating your changes due to time is not passing its not showing record.

Comment: Hi Stanislovas, the column which is storing is with time and date, if i hide time, then the data doesnt found. please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Format() function to achieve your goal.

=Format(Now(),"dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:00")

=Format(Now(),"dd-MM-yyyy 23:00:00")

[image]

Comment: Hi Daniel, I made changes but it showing error "The Property defaultvalue of report parameter 'toDate' doesnt have the expected type".